# Javascript countdown just working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, countdown

Well, I'm making a game, and in my game I have a countdown script in javascript that receives the date when the building upgrade is over, and makes a countdown, and when the countdown ends, executes a script that upgrades the building to the next level.

But just works in google chrome, and in the other browsers appears like that:

---

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox]

**Google Chrome**
[image: Google Chrome]

---

**Just the Javascript:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('europe/lisbon');
$datephp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


echo'

<script type="text/javascript">
function cdtd() {
    var xmas = new Date("' . $factory_date . '");
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = xmas.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#factory_upgrade").load("/include/factory_upgraded.php");
    $("#quantidade_fabricas").load("/include/factory_stats.php");
    }

    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;' .
    "var tempo=('0'  + hours).slice(-2)+':'+('0'  + minutes).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + seconds).slice(-2);"
    .
    '
    document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = tempo;
    var timer = setTimeout("cdtd()",1000);
}
</script>
';
```

---

**Complete function:**

```
function factory_update($get){

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$query00 = "SELECT * FROM factory_upgrading WHERE userid = '$userid'";
$result00 = mysql_query($query00) or die(mysql_error());

while($row00 = mysql_fetch_array($result00)){
$factory_upgrade = $row00['userid'];
}

if(!isset($factory_upgrade)){
echo "Sem melhoramentos.";
return 0;
}

$query01 = "SELECT * FROM factory_upgrading WHERE userid = '$userid'";
$result01 = mysql_query($query01) or die(mysql_error());

while($row01 = mysql_fetch_array($result01)){
$factory_level = $row01['new_level'];
$factory_date = $row01['upgraded'];
}


if ($get == "load")
{
echo '<div class="message_upgrades" ">';
echo '<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif"></img></div>';
echo '</div>';}

else
{

date_default_timezone_set('europe/lisbon');
$datephp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


echo'

<script type="text/javascript">
function cdtd() {
    var xmas = new Date("' . $factory_date . '");
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = xmas.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#factory_upgrade").load("/include/factory_upgraded.php");
    $("#quantidade_fabricas").load("/include/factory_stats.php");
    }

    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;' .
    "var tempo=('0'  + hours).slice(-2)+':'+('0'  + minutes).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + seconds).slice(-2);"
    .
    '
    document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = tempo;
    var timer = setTimeout("cdtd()",1000);
}
</script>
';

echo '<div class="success_upgrades">';
echo '<div class="upgrade_text"><b>Nivel: </b>' . $factory_level . '</div><div class="div_separator"></div><div class="upgrade_text"><b>Duração:</b>
 <div class="secsBox" id="secsBox"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">cdtd();</script></div><div class="div_separator"></div>
';
echo '<div id="close" class="stop_upgrade" ><a href="#" id="close" ><img src="/icon/x.png"></img></a></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<script>


    $(".stop_upgrade").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(factory_upgrade2).empty();



    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#factory_upgrade2").load("/include/upgrade_cancel.php");
    $("#factory_upgrade").load("/include/factory_update.php");
    $("#load").load("/include/cabecalho_content.php");
    $("#industrial").fadeIn();
                $(loader1).delay(1000).hide(0);
                }, 100);


    });


    </script>
    ';
}
}
```

Comment: why are you doing the output in php cannot you not do it nromally or via a js script file?

Comment: I have to put php variables in the middle of the javascript so I think is better that way :|

Comment: What would a typical `$factory_date` look like?

Comment: Any errors in the console of firefox? Does it work in IE?

Comment: what would the typical result of $factory_date be it might be that it not formatting correctly for the browser as in it might be of a string or integer etc

Comment: have you tried to hard code that in to your js and see what the result is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of `$factory_date` is invalid according to standard JavaScript and Chrome happens to be able to parse it.

For better results, stick to these `Date` constructors:

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: If the variable of $factory_date = 2013-12-30 22:21:01
How can I put that in a good format for all browsers?

Comment: Read my post and the link I provided. The different valid `dateString` are explained. You could always use whatever PHP object represents a date to extract year/month/day/hour/minute/second and use the last constructor. Be aware that the month parameter is 0-based in JavaScript.

Comment: There is probably also a simple way to get a unix epoch timestamp in PHP, you could use that.

Comment: Avoid `new Date(dateString);` as it is not consistently implemented in browsers, the others are fine.